# Error publishing application for iOS with Delphi XE8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, delphi

I'm trying to publish an application for iOS. I made all the necessary settings and it returns the .ipa.

Well, when I try to install the ipa on the device charges that the profile was not found. When I send debug the application typically runs on the iPhone.

When run on the command Delphi XE8 is giving the following error:

> e8008015: The target iOS device has not been provisioned with the provisioning profile that you configured in RAD Studio. 
>   You can either provision the target device with the configured provisioning profile, or change the RAD Studio project configuration to a different provisioning profile. See Completing the Provisioning Page. 
>   Ensure that your provisioning data in RAD Studio matches your iOS developer account, and not your Mac developer account. Be specially careful when you specify your iOS developer certificate name.

[image]

My setup screen in Delhi XE8

I followed this tutorial and it still fails
[Tutorial](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/sarinadupont/2015/01/29/ios-813-app-deployment-steps-for-xe7/)

Screen when I try to install the ipa iphone
[image]

Another detail is that the application loader does not accuse any error and allowed to rise to iTunes Connect.

Could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Tools->Options->Provisioning, and then read the paragraph you quoted again. :-) It's not *Project Options*, but *Tools Options*, and it's not *Version Info*.